# Celltable with fixed number of rows

Tags: java, gwt, celltable

I have 2 celltables on my page positioned vertically (one below the other). How can I set fixed number of rows in celltable (independently on the number of data rows)? E.g. when celltable contains 0 rows it should consist of some "blank" ones to keep fixed height.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
fixed number of rows?
```

[Celltable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html) Constructs a table with a `default` page size of 15.

If You want you can construct a `cell table` with `pageSize` like [CellTable(int pageSize)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html#CellTable%28%29),you can.

Or you can set later on with [setPageSize(int pageSize)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#setPageSize%28int%29).

Comment: but for empty celltable (with only header and no data in it) all items below it are just below table's header...

Comment: And please add some height to row also.